# {chinese} and {japanese} tags synonym of {cjk} tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I would like to suggest that the tags [chinese](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese) and [japanese](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) (the tag [korean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean) does not exist to date) should be treated as synonyms of the tag [cjk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cjk).

The reason is that this page primarily deals with typesetting and typographic considerations regarding Chinese, Japanese or Korean, and relevant questions virtually always relate to all three languages. Prominent examples are questions regarding the set up of CJK fonts or regarding the typesetting of languages with scripts that use ideographic characters (although Korean rarely uses them, Korean script is still typeset in a way that matches typesetting ideographic characters).

You are welcome to vote for or against this proposal on the relevant [sub page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).

*(Note that you need to have [a total answer score of 5 or more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) on the relevant tag to be able to vote for tag synonyms.)*

Comment: I don't see the proposal on the tag synonym page (only tikz-node, calligraphy, url, hyperlink and plain).

Comment: Regarding the proposal itself: it makes sense I guess, but it is maybe not really needed? [chinese] and [japanese] are used mostly together with [cjk] (or something more specific like [ctex], [xecjk], [uptex], [ptex]) anyway, and they are low frequency tags overall.

Comment: Hm, I don't know why you can't see them. Maybe you need a certain proficiency to vote for tag synonyms? Anyways, you are right, the tags are mostly used together, which only underlines that they are indeed kind of synonyms.

Comment: You're right, https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms says _Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms_ and I only have a score of 4 for [cjk] :)

Comment: This explains the quite low rate of votings for tag synonyms in general. Well, we know what to do then! =D I am out of votes for today though.

Comment: @JasperHabicht this is the one atleast showing something: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active

Comment: Your link is to the page with all active synonyms. My link is to the page with the tag synonyms pending approval. You may not see anything on this page if you don't have sufficient privilege.

Comment: noted, I knew this anyway. Please ping me as @VScode, otherwise I wont get notified.